# Target a specific attribute table

Tags: python, pyqgis, qt-designer, combo-box

I'm new to PyQGIS and I'm stuck here.

So I've created a ComboBox so the user could select which layer he wants to work with. Everything's fine so far. I've also added all layers but now I'm having issues to filter the output in the 2nd ComboBox.

```
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    self.dlg.ComboAll.addItem(layer.name())

self.dlg.ComboAll.currentIndexChanged.connect(IndexChange)
```

So this is how I prompt all layers in my ComboBox and get the information that the user has choosen another option.

```
def IndexChange():
    selectedLayer = self.dlg.ComboAll.currentIndex()
    #Prompt every fields of selectedLayer in ComboLayer
```

And this is how I get the number of the selected layer.
But I don't know what to do after that.
For example, if the user choose the layer number 3 I only want fields from this layer appearing in my second ComboBox.

Answer (score 8):

Below a code with a simple `QDialog` with 2 comboBoxes (specialized for QGIS to display layers and fields) :

```py
class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self._combo_lyr = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self)
        self._combo_fld = QgsFieldComboBox(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self._combo_lyr)
        self.layout.addWidget(self._combo_fld)
        # init fields data
        self.IndexChanged(0)
        # signals
        self._combo_lyr.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.IndexChanged)

    def IndexChanged(self, index):
        # see help(QgsMapLayerComboBox.layer)
        selected_layer = self._combo_lyr.layer(index)
        # see help(QgsMapLayerComboBox.layer)
        self._combo_fld.setLayer(selected_layer)
        self._combo_fld.setCurrentIndex(0)

md = MyDialog()
md.show()
```

> ***QgsMapLayerComboBox***
>
> **.layer**(*self*, `layerIndex`: int) → `QgsMapLayer`
>
> Returns the layer currently shown at the specified index within the
> combo box.

- [*source* : PyQGIS API Documentation `QgsMapLayerComboBox.layer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsMapLayerComboBox.html?highlight=qgsmaplayercombobox#qgis.gui.QgsMapLayerComboBox.layer)

> ***QgsFieldComboBox***
>
> **.setLayer**(*self*, layer: `QgsMapLayer`)
>
> Sets the layer for which fields are listed in the combobox. If no
> layer is set or a non-vector layer is set then the combobox will be
> empty.

- [*source* : PyQGIS API Documentation `QgsFieldComboBox.setLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsFieldComboBox.html?highlight=qgsfieldcombobox#qgis.gui.QgsFieldComboBox.setLayer)

Comment: Could you add some comments on this code ? I'm really beginning and I still have issues understanding some lines. Especially 
```selected_layer = self._combo_lyr.layer(index)
  self._combo_fld.setLayer(selected_layer)```
My current objective in order to understand is to print selected layer's fields in the console.
Thank you very much for your time !

Comment: @NewbieCoder: I hope my post edit helps you.